# How to connect worklight app to remote db2 DB from local worklight development server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, worklight-studio

I want to connect remote db2 database to my worklight app deployed on local worklight development server.

Answer (score 0):

You don't connect your 'app' to a database per se...

You either use DB2 as the database for the MobileFirst Server,
Or you use DB2 as the database that your *adapter* request will connect to to fetch some data.

- You cannot change the database of the MobileFirst Server in your **development environment** (= MobileFirst Studio).
- You can select which database to use for the server as part of a **production installation**.
- To use DB2 as the database to connect an adapter to, [create an SQL adapter](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/server-side-development/javascript-adapters/js-sql-adapter/.

Comment: Iam using db2 database as sql adapter but my sql adapter does not invoke procedure... Sql adapter not connecting to remote db2 database... Iam deploying my adapter on my local mobile first server...

Comment: Start adding logs then... and your code how you call the adapter, and whether it works or not in studio...